# How to read from multiple different sources concurrently?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am extracting data from 3 data sources, CSV_1, CSV_2, and DB 1.  CSV_1 and CSV_2 have different schemas and encodings.  I am using `pandas.read_csv` to read the CSVs `pandas.read_sql` to pull from the DB.  I am new to concurrency/parallelism but from my understanding since IO is my constraint here multithreading could help me achieve speed gains.

I thought I would be able to use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and its map method to read the csvs in parallel, like so:

```
files = ['csv_1.csv', 'csv_2.csv']

with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
    results = executor.map(pd.read_csv, files)
```

but from what I've seen since I need to apply different parameters to read_csv (i.e. encoding and dtypes) this wont work. Is there a way to do use the same function with different parameters for each iterable?  This part alone, reading two different csvs asynchronously that require different `pd.read_csv` parameters would be a huge win.

Ideally I would also like to add a third thread that reads from the DB.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. You just need an interim function that knows how to expand the single parameter used by `map` into the call you want. In the first example, you can have some canned types. This is nice because its easy to see the parameters you like for each type

```
def csv_reader(params):
    filename, csv_type = *params
    if csv_type == 'footype':
        return pd.read_csv(filename, sep="|")
    elif csv_type == 'bartype':
        return pd.read_csv(filename, columns=["A", "B", "C"])

files = [('csv_1.csv', 'footype'), ('csv_2.csv', 'bartype')]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
    results = executor.map(csv_reader, files)
```

But you could always make it generic

```
def csv_reader_generic(params):
    filename, args, kw = *params
    return pd.read_csv(filename, *args, **kwargs)

files = [('csv_1.csv', tuple(), {"sep":"|"}), 
    ('csv_2.csv', tuple(), {"columns":["A", "B", "C"]})]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
    results = executor.map(csv_reader_generic, files)
```

Answer (score 0):

tdelaney's thorough answer covers your asked question, but to offer another suggestion, moving away from CSV as your storage format could make an even bigger difference if you have control over the file creation.

Using the moderately large dataframes I generated below, writing 2 CSVs takes 56.2 seconds, and reading takes 5.66 seconds in series or 3.06 using the threads. However, switching to Parquet makes the writes take 2 seconds and the reads 317ms, while also cutting the file size in less than half.

```
In [282]: %time df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000000, 20)))
Wall time: 174 ms

In [283]: %time df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000000, 20)))
Wall time: 190 ms

In [284]: %time df1.to_csv("test1.csv", index=False)
Wall time: 28 s

In [285]: %time df2.to_csv("test2.csv", index=False)
Wall time: 28.2 s

In [286]: %time df1 = pd.read_csv("test1.csv"); df2 = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")
Wall time: 5.66 s

In [287]: files = ["test1.csv", "test2.csv"]

In [288]: %time with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as executor: results = executor.map(pd.read_csv, files)
Wall time: 3.06 s

In [289]: %time df1.to_parquet('test1.parquet')
Wall time: 939 ms

In [290]: %time df2.to_parquet('test2.parquet')
Wall time: 917 ms

In [291]: %time df1 = pd.read_parquet("test1.parquet"); df2 = pd.read_parquet("test2.parquet")
Wall time: 317 ms

In [292]: !ls -lh test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 Randy 197609 360K Aug 30  2017 test.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 Randy 197609 369M May 27 21:53 test1.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 Randy 197609 158M May 27 21:54 test1.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 Randy 197609 369M May 27 21:53 test2.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 Randy 197609 158M May 27 21:55 test2.parquet
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback and examples.  I actually use parquet pretty extensively, in this case ill be reading in the data from the CSVs/DB, merging it, and outputting it to a parquet file.